# Why ArrayAdapter.getView() is called?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In my application I'm using ArrayAdapter for a ListView. When I debug the application, I realized that in every scroll of the ListView `ArrayAdapter.getView()` is called.

Why getView() is called everytime? Because I'm doing so much work in getView() like adding event listeners, setting images and so on..

Comment: I mean, the list view is already created and nothing will change. So why getView() is called only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `default` behaviour of `ListView` that it `recycles` the views of ListView. [**Here**](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) is a nice and complete explanation for the same.

Answer (score 1):

**getView** is called to show list items in a ListView. You should not do excessive tasks (as you mentioned) in getView, else it will slow the overall performance of your ListView.